# Is there a memory efficient way to change a higher level variable or counter in R with lapply?

Tags: r, optimization, lapply, immutability

I have a function in which a variable is initialized and then modified inside an `lapply` function.

```r
f <- function() {
    a <- 1
    lapply(seq_len(1000000), function(i) {
        print(paste0('a:', a))
        b <- a + 1
        a <- b
        print(paste0('a:', a))
        print(paste0('b:', b))
    })
}

f()
# [1] "a:1"
# [1] "a:2"
# [1] "b:2"
# [1] "a:1"
# [1] "a:2"
# [1] "b:2"
...
```

However since `lapply` cannot modify variables in the parent scope, reassigning `a` inside the function does not carry throught every iteration giving me the wrong result. So I used the `<<-` operator which allows me to get the correct results, but at the cost of a much higher execution time on large datasets.

```r
f2 <- function() {
    a <- 1
    lapply(seq_len(1000000), function(i) {
        print(paste0('a:', a))
        b <- a + 1
        a <<- b
        print(paste0('a:', a))
        print(paste0('b:', b))
    })
}

f2()
# [1] "a:1"
# [1] "a:2"
# [1] "b:2"
# [1] "a:2"
# [1] "a:3"
# [1] "b:3"
...
```

Is there a way to change a variable in this way without having to make a copy of it? The only solution I can think of is to use a `data.table` row to store my values and perform in-place changes.

Comment: Why not use `i`? you are already looping over `i`

Comment: I have an increment of + 1 as an example here. In reality, I'm assigning `a` to other values.

Comment: Why not just use a for-loop/while loop?

Comment: That was my first approach, but since I'd like to accumulate values, I thought lapply would be more efficient.

Comment: You can accumulate values using for loop. Just predefine a list ie `my_list <- vector('list', 10)` to predefine a list of length 10

Comment: Woudn't that still be slow as I can't make the modification in place for `a`? As I understand, the code without `<<-` is running faster because it doesn't need to change the parent `a`.

Comment: with the normal while/for loop, you do not need `<<-` since a and b will change within the scope